# Reformatting datetime string with 8 decimal points on seconds

Tags: python, datetime

I am looking to convert the following string `originalString = "2018-10-21 12:51:00.7134616 +00:00"` to extract the datetime info for year, month, day, hour and minute to give `dtObj = datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 21, 12, 51)`

**Attempt**

First removing the colon from the time zone element

```
correctedString = re.sub(r'([-+]\d{2}):(\d{2})(?:(\d{2}))?$', r'\1\2\3', originalString)
```

Then looking to convert to `datetime`

```
cor = datetime.strptime(correctedString, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z')
```

However, I receive the error "`ValueError: time data '2018-10-21 12:51:00.7134616 +0000' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %z'`"

Any advice on thia would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There's one too many decimal places on the second (`%f` is microsecond, so 6).

A simple way you could fix this is by also doing a `sub` with `(\d{6})\d` to `\1`, although there might be a cleaner way to fix it.

This will also truncate instead of rounding, but you probably won't need it to be that precise unless you need all of the digits and rounding also wouldn't work in that case.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am happy with truncation as I only need precision as far as the minute level

Answer (score 0):

`dateutil`'s [parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) does a good job inferring the format and also accepting more than 6 digits of fractional seconds:

```
import dateutil

originalString = "2018-10-21 12:51:00.7134616 +00:00"

dateutil.parser.parse(originalString)
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 21, 12, 51, 0, 713461, tzinfo=tzutc())
```